# F# Multidimensional array comprehensions

Tags: arrays, f#

Is there a syntax for creating multidimensional array using comprehensions is F#?
This is really easy for jagged arrays:

```
let weights1 = [|
                  [|3.0|]
                  [|1.0|]
               |]
```

Sure that I can than convert this jagged array to multidimensional array:

```
let weights = Array2D.init 2 2 (fun i j -> weights1.[i].[j])
```

But isn't there a syntax way of doing the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`array2D`<sup>MSDN</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620670.aspx) operator, passing a sequence of sequences (or jagged array):

```
array2D [[3.0]; [1.0]]
```